# EventSource misses first messages before addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, race-condition, server-sent-events

How to prevent new EventSource from missing first messages before addEventListener called (in pure vanilla JS)?

The problem is race condition between start data receiving and handler subscribing due to non atomic operation create-subscribe.
It would be nice to have a way to create EventSource in closed state or pass subscribers right into constructor.

I can see two workarounds:

- to have additional API to notify server that listeners are ready or to request first data after subscribers set
- to add some sleep timeout in server before initial data transfer.

They both are ugly enough to not even try to use SSE and go to WebSocket. But it's another question.

Comment: How is it taking such a long time between the EventSource creation and adding the event listener? Maybe improve that.

Comment: Is this a practical question or only a theoretical one? Did you face this issue? I am not myself a ninja in SSE, but from what I understand, you need to have a routine running on your server, that will send the events when needed. However, this routine is only ever started when the EventSource makes the first request to your server. So you should never have this race-condition: `var src = new EventSource('/yourSSEurl/'); src.onmessage = e => {};` by the time onmessage is applied, the request should still be sent to the server, and you can be sure that the Event won't have fired yet.

Comment: @Herohtar I faced this situation trying to create EventSource and subscribe in Chrome Console. So, there was a lag in seconds between creation and adding a listener. Yes, in real life in script the lag will be near milliseconds, but it still exists.

Comment: @Kaiido EventSource makes request before listeners added.

Comment: @SerG yes, the request should be posted by the browser as soon as possible, in parallel. However, there is no way that a `MessageEvent` fires on your EventSource before you have time to add the listener to it. The MessageEvent will get dispatched only at the beginning of the next event loop, doing `new EventSource(url).onchange = e => {}` is synchronous, and thus you'll have your message firing in your listener.

Comment: @Kaiido It sounds like an answer. But while I agree that this construction is synchronous, I'm still in doubt about synchronicity of EventSource internal realisation (just receiving data from SOCKET without listerners) though. Could it be proved by some documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I faced this situation trying to create EventSource and subscribe in Chrome Console. So, there was a lag in seconds between creation and adding a listener. Yes, in real life in script the lag will be near milliseconds, but it still exists.

And that was the cause of your problem; the entire reason you experienced it was because you entered each line manually through the console. You cannot expect code entered that way to behave the same as code running sequentially in the browser directly. In "real life" *the problem does not exist* because the time between statements is *less* than milliseconds, but more than that, the code is synchronous and is blocking the event loop, so incoming events will not ever be missed in that situation. To have closer to realistic behavior from the console you will need to paste *both* the creation and listener assignment statements as a single block at the same time. If you do that, you will see that no events are ever missed.

Comment: Still, I have an issue on how close to the EventSource I declare the listeners. If it's being return from a function, the error listener misses a 404, for example.